# Why is there no output for mapview() command in R 4.2.2 (August 2023)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, r-sf, r-mapview, tigris, geojsonio

After installing the **"mapview" package in R 4.2.2** and importing its library into a Jupyter notebook, **I cannot create any maps**. Although the data is loaded, any attempt to render a map figure when running a code block results in no output and no error messages.

Below are my session info and the code as an example.

```
sessionInfo()
```

> ```
> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] geojsonio_0.11.1 mapview_2.11.0   tigris_2.0.3    
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.10         lattice_0.20-45     png_0.1-8          
>  [4] class_7.3-20        digest_0.6.31       utf8_1.2.3         
>  [7] V8_4.3.3            IRdisplay_1.1       R6_2.5.1           
> [10] repr_1.1.6          stats4_4.2.2        evaluate_0.21      
> [13] e1071_1.7-13        geojson_0.3.4       httr_1.4.6         
> [16] pillar_1.9.0        rlang_1.1.1         lazyeval_0.2.2     
> [19] curl_5.0.1          uuid_1.1-0          raster_3.6-23      
> [22] webshot_0.5.5       jqr_1.2.3           stringr_1.5.0      
> [25] htmlwidgets_1.6.2   munsell_0.5.0       proxy_0.4-27       
> [28] compiler_4.2.2      pkgconfig_2.0.3     base64enc_0.1-3    
> [31] htmltools_0.5.5     tidyselect_1.2.0    httpcode_0.3.0     
> [34] tibble_3.2.1        codetools_0.2-18    fansi_1.0.4        
> [37] crayon_1.5.2        dplyr_1.1.2         sf_1.0-14          
> [40] rappdirs_0.3.3      crul_1.4.0          grid_4.2.2         
> [43] jsonlite_1.8.5      satellite_1.0.4     lifecycle_1.0.3    
> [46] DBI_1.1.3           magrittr_2.0.3      units_0.8-2        
> [49] scales_1.2.1        KernSmooth_2.23-20  cli_3.6.1          
> [52] stringi_1.7.12      leaflet_2.1.2       sp_2.0-0           
> [55] generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.6.2         IRkernel_1.3.2.9000
> [58] geojsonsf_2.0.3     tools_4.2.2         leafem_0.2.0       
> [61] glue_1.6.2          crosstalk_1.2.0     fastmap_1.1.1      
> [64] colorspace_2.1-0    terra_1.7-39        classInt_0.4-9     
> [67] pbdZMQ_0.3-9
> ```

**Here I install packages and upload libraries.** When loading packages, I received warnings that tigris, mapview, and geojsonio were built under newer R versions than mine. This was also mentioned when installing tigris: "To enable caching of data, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)` in your R script or .Rprofile.

```
install.packages("tigris")
install.packages("mapview")
install.packages("geojsonio")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("leaflet")
install.packages("sf")

library(tigris)
library(mapview)
library(geojsonio)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
```

**Then I entered the following command** and the output was what seems to be a df table.

```
breweries
```

Then I attempted to **create a simple map** **using mapview**, but the code ran resulting in no output and no error message.

```
mapview(breweries)
mapview(breweries, zcol = "founded")
```

Although StackOverflow recommends not posting pictures of code, I don't know how to better explain in text or illustrate how an output doesn't exist. So here is a photo of my result.

[Photo of no output when using multiple mapview(breweries) commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnW0d.png)

Comment: While it is not practical for me to try to reproduce your error - I don't have a Windows machine running Jupyter notebooks on hand - I have encountered this kind of error in the past. It involved flat geobuff support, and could be resolved by using setting `mapviewOptions(fgb = FALSE)` before the mapview call. Do give it a try if you can...

Comment: This does not work. I am still not getting any output when I run these commands along with the suggested mapviewOptions command. Do you have any other fixes?

Comment: unfortunately this is all that I can offer without actually running your code :(